# How to disable the shortcut "press super key twice" in 22.04

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys, 22.04

The system shortcut has be added from 22.04:

```
Super or Super + S to get into Activities overview.
Hit Super twice or Super + A for ‘Show Applications’ (app grid) screen.
```

How do I disable the shortcut for "press super key twice"?
I don't need it because simply pressing Super + A brings me to the 'Show Applications' screen.